# How to add custom import options for CSV files in prestashop (for categories)?

Tags: csv, import, prestashop

I am currently trying to import a csv file with my previous categories from another website , before that I went to the category_lang table inside prestashop (version 8) to add two fields for the data I wanted to keep , but it wasn't enough , when it came time to import the file I believed that when I needed to match the csv columns to the options inside prestashop it would have given me the option to match the fields that I added before , but it wasn't the case , do you have an idea to add the option to match the custom field I added into the category_lang table ? thank you for your time !

I tried to add my custom fields inside the table category_lang of prestashop and try to see the fields  I added inside the import module of prestashop and it didn't work .

[given options to match the columns of the csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yWFE.png)
[fields that I added into the category_lang table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT6t6.png)